# Leaflet map tiles don't load properly when displayed in flexdashboard tabsets

Tags: r, leaflet, flexdashboard

If I toggle between the tabs in the html file rendered from the following Rmarkdown file, Leaflet map tiles don't load properly. When I resize the html file, tiles show properly, but subsequent toggle again leads to partial loading of map tiles. I came across this [SO question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/224932/143567) that discusses similar problem, but I am unsure on how to use **invalidateSize** method on leaflet objects created via R leaflet package.

````r
---
title: "Example for StackOverflow"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    theme:
      version: 4
      bootswatch: minty
runtime: shinyrmd
---

# Page 1

## Sub page 1 {.tabset}

### Map 1

```{r map1-out}
leaflet::leafletOutput("map1")
```

```{r map1, context = "server"}
output$map1 <- leaflet::renderLeaflet({
  leaflet::leaflet() |>
    leaflet::addProviderTiles("CartoDB.Positron") |>
    leaflet::setView(-88, 34, 4)
})
```

### Map 2

```{r map2-out}
leaflet::leafletOutput("map2")
```

```{r map2, context = "server"}
output$map2 <- leaflet::renderLeaflet({
  leaflet::leaflet() |>
    leaflet::addProviderTiles("Stamen.TonerLite") |>
    leaflet::setView(-88, 34, 4)
})
```
````

[image]